# XGBoost decision tree selection

Tags: python, decision-tree, xgboost

I have a question regarding which decision tree should I choose from `XGBoost`.

I will use the following code as an example.

```
#import packages
import xgboost as xgb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create DMatrix
df_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data = X, label = y)

# set up parameter dictionary
params = {"objective":"reg:linear", "max_depth":2}

#train the model
xg_reg = xgb.train(params = params, dtrain = df_dmatrix, num_boost_round = 10)

#plot the tree
xgb.plot_tree(xg_reg, num_trees = n) # my question related to here
```

I create 10 trees in the `xg_reg` model, and I can plot any one of them by setting `n` in my last code equal to the index of the tree.

My question is: how can I know which tree best explains the dataset? Is it always the last one? Or should I determine which features I want to include in the tree, and then choose the tree which contains the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how I can know which tree explains the data set best?

XGBoost is an implementation of Gradient Boosted Decision Trees (GBDT). Roughly speaking, GBDT is a sequence of trees each one improving the prediction of the previous using residual boosting. So the tree that explains the data best is the `n - 1`th.

You can read more about GBDT [here](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2016/06/24/gradient_boosting_explained.html)

> Or should I determine which features I want to include in the tree, and then choose the tree which contains the features?

All the trees are trained with the same base features, they just get `residuals` added at every boosting iteration. So you could not determine the best tree in this way. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJAKyIww1FI&list=PLpQWTe-45nxL3bhyAJMEs90KF_gZmuqtm&index=50) there is an intuitive explanation of residuals.

Comment: Thanks. SO is it true that the more rounds we let the model iterate, the better the tree is? So we need to consider the trade-off between time spent on training the model and the accuracy of the model.

Comment: No is not true. If you keep training after a while you will start to overfit and your model will lose predictive power because it's becoming worse and worse at generalizing. You can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting